# Why can't my app find the newly taken image?

Tags: android, android-camera

My app allow user to take picture and immediately so it in the gallery (all pictures in external storage).
However, I couldn't view my newly taken picture in the gallery. I am sure the picture is taken, as I can view it in file manager. And the path is correct. Why can't my app recognize the picture it just took. What do I miss?

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

The code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { // the listener
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(photoFile != null) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
        ImageSelectionActivity.photoUri = uri;
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/MyApp";
    File storageDir = new File(dir);
    if(!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdir();
    }
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    return image;
}

// The CursorLoader
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // Get relevant columns for use later.
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    };

    Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            this,
            queryUri,
            projection,
            null,
            null, // Selection args (none).
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC" // Sort order.
    );
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

Comment: you storing new images in DCIM/Myapp ?

Comment: @pratz9999, yes, is it the problem?

Comment: The pictures you are taking and the pictures you store are making two copies. You matched the name ?

Answer (score 0):

I would enter ImageView/TextView(Placeholder) in the same Activity use this function.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, 
Intent data) {  
if (requestCode == RESULT_OK)   {
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagsView)).setImageBitmap(photo);

 }
 }
```

this brings much more then viewing, log. becouse there is much more data you can pass.
you can see/regonizeo, if every code dos correctly to the ImageView/TextView.
From the ImageView/Textview on, you can Test Methods, to save Data with the final Information you would to use from the TextView.
Some ideas from StackOverflow, would me help also. maybee someone write, good enought to understand, answers on your question.

Comment: if you start an activity with intent intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);, you the data will be null. your solution is for thumbnail. But the problem here is why I can't see it in the app while it is actually stored in the phone.

Comment: Like you say, i found diffrent proplems on diffrent devices.
Samsu.. registers the image, but shows it, in thirt Apps, broke. 
other devices needs to get, full information.
  
Let your file implements, Media Scanner. It interpret, your file for the System.
or add the preferred content provider mamuell a new record.